# Use sum of calculation as data for Google Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I'm attempting to create a chart with the Google Visualisation API using a javascript calculation that sums the values from checked radio buttons, however I have been unable to get the API to accept the output as data for a scatter chart.

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var radios = $('input[type=radio]');

  var evalResult = function(){

    var numQuestions = 80;
    var sum1 = 0;
    var sum2 = 0;

    var expr_str = '';
    for(var i = 1; i <= numQuestions; i++){
      var q = $("input[type=radio][name=q"+i+"]:checked").val();
      var value = q.split(',');
      sum1 += parseInt(value[0]);
      sum2 += parseInt(value[1]);

    }

    var total = eval("['',''],[" + sum1 + "," + sum2 + "]");
  }

  evalResult();
  radios.change(evalResult);

});
```

The impression I had was that all I needed to do was format the data in such a way that the API would accept it, then call it like this:

```
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(total);
```

I've tried various different solutions, some suggested by the documentation, others that were examples of similar approaches I found elsewhere, however nothing seems to be working. Being a bit of a newbie at this sort of thing I'm obviously missing something simple or just doing it wrong. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out why it wasn't working, needed to use a format that the DataTable could understand.

```
total = [['',''],[sum1, sum2]];
```

Now it works as is should.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define `total` before your function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var radios = $('input[type=radio]');
  var total = 0;                                 //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< here
  var evalResult = function(){

    var numQuestions = 80;
    var sum1 = 0;
    var sum2 = 0;

    var expr_str = '';
    for(var i = 1; i <= numQuestions; i++){
      var q = $("input[type=radio][name=q"+i+"]:checked").val();
      var value = q.split(',');
      sum1 += parseInt(value[0]);
      sum2 += parseInt(value[1]);

    }

    total = eval("['',''],[" + sum1 + "," + sum2 + "]"); // <<< remove var from here
  }
  alert(total);   // output should be 0
  evalResult();
  alert(total);   // output should be your total
  radios.change(evalResult);

});
```

Comment: I thought it might have something to do with defining the variable however this doesn't seem to make a difference, the chart is still not getting drawn. The function is working as I can output as HTML, but when I try to put it through the API nothing happens.

Comment: @DanielJarick is this link https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en   what you looking for ???

Comment: I've spent some time reading the documentation already, it's concerned mostly with either manually entering the DataTable or querying a database. I have seen references to examples on the support forum similar to what I want to achieve but they were not exactly what I was looking for. I'll take another look at them but I don't think they will be of much help.